# Javascript "this" reference for onclick event not working

Tags: javascript, this

I'm trying to call a function with the "onclick" event as so:

```
<td id="A1" onclick="move()" class="white"></td>
<td id="A2" onclick="move()" class="painted bp"></td>
<td id="A3" onclick="move()" class="white"></td>
```

In the function itself, i refer to "this":

```
function move(e){
    var myId = this.id;
    alert("myId");
}
```

When I run the whole thing, the alert says 'undefined'. When I try `alert(this)` I get [object window].
I'm working with IE9, btw.
Thanks

Comment: This is how it works, `this` is replaced by `window` when nothing else provided. What do you expect?

Comment: FYI, the function where `this` refers to the element is inside the quotes. Basically `onclick="move()"` is same as `.onclick = function( event ) { move(); }`, where as you are expecting it to behave like `.onclick = move;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When calling a function from an event handler, its `this` isn't set by the handler (though you can pass `this` from the handler per Xdazz's answer, or set `this` per Kyle's answer). Another approach is to extract the sender element from the event object associated with the event:

```
function move(e) {
    if (!e)
        e = window.event;
    var sender = e.srcElement || e.target;

    //maybe some nested element.. find the actual table cell parent.
    while (sender && sender.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "td")
        sender = sender.parentNode;

    var myId = sender.id;
    alert(myId);
}
​
```

You also must pass the event explicitly:

```
onclick="move(event)"
```

Note that when the table cell has nested elements they will be the "sender" thus to grab the desired element (which is the table cell) you have to traverse upwards. *To avoid all this headache see below how to attach the handlers through code*.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/H9YDn/5/).

That said, better practice would be to bind the click event through code instead of inline - don't mix HTML with JavaScript. To achieve this, have such code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var arrCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrCells.length; i++) {
        var oCell = arrCells[i];
        if (oCell.id && oCell.id.substr(0, 1) == "A") {
            oCell.onclick = move;
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code in place, you can remove the inline `onclick=` calls from the HTML and keep your original function - the `this` will point to the clicked table cell.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H9YDn/2/).

Comment: `e.target` and `e.srcElement` are not necessarily the element that has the handler. They represent the most deeply nested element that received the event. *(I would assume the `<td>` elements have some content.)*

Comment: @user1689607 might be so, but so far it always worked for me and it should work just fine in this case as well.

Comment: Sure, if the `<td>` elements never have descendant elements, it'll work.

Comment: @user1689607 oh my.. [you are correct](http://jsfiddle.net/H9YDn/4/) (clicking the first cell A1 will show D1) - need to edit my post.

Comment: @user1689607 what if there are img elements within some of the td's, and they have an onclick event of their own? would it get priority over the `<td>`s onclick event automatically?

Comment: @Tomcatom: The handler for the `img` will be invoked first. Then the event "bubbles" up through its ancestors and invokes any `onclick` events it finds along the way. So the handler on the `<td>` will also be invoked. But there are ways to stop the bubbling at the `<img>` if needed.

Comment: Care to explain them in chat?

Comment: @Tomcatom who are you referring to?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Your updated solution will certainly work... as long as there are no nested tables being clicked. ;-)

Comment: Either one of you actually, but specifically to @user1689607 :)
But I have since seen your update solution and I think all is clear.
Thanks, you two!

Comment: Chrome complains Cannot read property 'id' of null, I am pretty confused about it.

Comment: @analysiser what is your code? It's pretty specific example, looking for a parent `<td>`.

Answer (score 14):

`this` is the `window` object in your code.

You could pass `this` as the parameter.

```
<td id="A1" onclick="move(this)" class="white"></td>
```

then:

```
function move(ele){
    var myId = ele.id;
    alert("myId");
}
```

Comment: You just save my day ;) Thx !!

Answer (score 5):

```
<td id="A1" onclick="move.call(this)" class="white"></td>
```

Now `this` will refer to the `td` element in your `move` function.

Comment: Now *this* is the way to do it. +1

Comment: You could make it even a little better if you pass `event` as the second arg to `.call()`. That way even old IE will get the event object in the function, just like a normal handler.

Comment: good point! I didn't want to confuse the OP by adding `event`. I was attempting a solution that was super simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the event target instead to get the dom element you are looking for:

```
function move(e) {
  alert(e.target);
}
```

Comment: Actually this gives me an error: `Unable to get value of the property 'target': object is null or undefined`
This is IE9

Comment: Ok the error went away when I passed the event explicitly as @Shadow Wizard suggested. thanks!

Comment: `e.target` is not necessarily the same as the element OP is targeting.

Comment: @Tomcatom see my updated answer and [this test case](http://jsfiddle.net/H9YDn/4/) - when the cell got nested elements, such code will "fail", giving back the wrong ID. (not my downvote BTW - this answer is not wrong in my opinion)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I tried your latest version, and I attached the events using a loop instead of within the html, but when I tried `oCell.onclick = move(this);` instead of `oCell.onclick = move;` I got an "Not implemented" error

Comment: @Tomcatom no, that's wrong. `oCell.onclick = move;` is the proper way and you will have `this` just fine inside the function.