# How to check checkbox checked or not using javascript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

How to check checkbox checked or not using javascript ?

I have a lot of checkbox (dynamic data) . I want to know how can i check when checked chekcbox >= '1' using javascript ?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="test[]" onclick="test_fn()"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="test[]" onclick="test_fn()"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="test[]" onclick="test_fn()"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="4" name="test[]" onclick="test_fn()"/>

<script>
function test_fn() {
// check it's have checked checkbox or not ? //
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass `this` in your `inline` handler,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="test[]" onclick="test_fn(this)"/>
```

And use `this.checked` to find out whether it is checked or not,

```
function test_fn(elem) {
 alert(elem.checked);
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9h4pek0L/1/)

To check, if the the checked check box greater than or equal to 1, then just do

```
function test_fn(elem) {
  if (document.querySelectorAll("input[name='test[]']:checked").length >= 1) {
    alert("yes it is greater than or equal to 1")
  }
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9h4pek0L/5/)

Comment: @mongmongseesee Do you want something like that. See my answer.

Comment: no, i don't want to alert when checked, i want to check it's have checked checkbox >= '1' or not ?

Comment: on https://jsfiddle.net/9h4pek0L/3/ when i uncheck for all it,s still alert yes it is greater than or equal to 1 ?

Comment: on https://jsfiddle.net/9h4pek0L/4/ , When i checked 2 checkbox it's alert yes it is greater than or equal to 1 OK ^^ but when uncheck 1 checkbox why not alert  yes it is greater than or equal to 1 ?

Comment: @mongmongseesee Sorry I misunderstood your requirement. Just check now, https://jsfiddle.net/9h4pek0L/5/

Comment: Yes , ^_^ but can i apply this code for work on ie7 ?

(querySelectorAll not work on ie7)

Comment: @mongmongseesee Don't forget to accept the answer as well as don't forget to remove the downvote you cast. ^_^

Comment: @mongmongseesee IE7 was dead already. Announced by microsoft.

Comment: @mongmongseesee Can you read it? https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support So kindly ask your app users to upgrade their browsers to recent one. IE > 9 supports querySelectors

Answer (score 1):

```
function test_fn()
{
    if (this.checked) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

**Edit:**

`this` reference won't work in this case, thanks to @RajaprabhuAravindasamy for pointing this out, read the comments or check this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820724/javascript-this-reference-for-onclick-event-not-working) for more information.

You need to pass a reference explicitly to the checkbox element:

```
function test_fn (el)
{
    if (el.checked) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

As for how to know if checked boxes count is more than one you can simply use a global variable to keep a track of the count like this:

```
var count = 0;

function test_fn (el)
{
    el.checked ? count++ : count--;
    return count > 1;
    // if (count > 1) alert ("count is more than 1");
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/wvkzfzpv/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9h4pek0L/ This will be output for this code.  This inside a plain function will point the window object.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I was just testing it and `this` seems to be undefined, why is `this` not working?

Comment: this inside a plain function will point to window. This is not just like binding explicit event handler. So widow.checked will be evaluated to undefined.